# Отслеживание состояния компонентов через систему событий в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Не могу до конца понять возможности системы событий в Unity и когда именно ее следует применять. Большинство туториалов по системе событий, с которыми удалось ознакомиться, показывают как устроены эвенты с точки зрения синтаксиса, но не дают представления о том, какие конкретно дают возможности события с точки зрения контроля происходящего в коде, особенно интересуют ситуации, когда можно использовать события, как альтернативу Upadate.

К примеру, такая ситуация. Есть Canvas, на нем есть компонент Canvas Group и в нем есть свойство Interactable. Это свойство динамически меняется через другие скрипты, соответственно, нет точного понимания, когда именно произойдет изменение свойства Interactable. Можно ли в данном случае использовать только систему событий и отследить момент, когда именно произойдет изменение свойства Interactable?
То есть, можно ли заменить этот код:

```
_canvasGroup = Canvas.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();

void Update()
{
   if (_canvasGroup.interactable == true)
       //action
}
```

на примерно что-то такое:

```
Event OnCanvasChanged;

void Start()
{
    OnCanvasChanged.AddListener(Cnanging);
}

void Changing()
{
   if(_canvas.interactable == true)
        {
            //action
        }
        if (_canvas.interactable == false)
        {
            //action
        }
}
```

Или без Update все равно не обойтись? Заранее спасибо за любую помощь и подсказки.

Answer (score 0):

При изменении `_canvas.interactable` вызывать ивент, на этот ивент подписать нужные методы.

```
public class SomeCanvas : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action<bool> ActiveStateChanged;
        
    [SerializeField] private CanvasGroup _canvasGroup;

    public void Activate()
    {
        SetActiveState(true);
    }

    public void Deactivate()
    {
        SetActiveState(false);
    }

    private void SetActiveState(bool state)
    {
        if (_canvasGroup.interactable == state) return;
        
        _canvasGroup.interactable = state;
        ActiveStateChanged?.Invoke(state);
    }
}

public class NotSomeCanvas : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private SomeCanvas _someCanvas;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _someCanvas.ActiveStateChanged += LogActiveState;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        _someCanvas.ActiveStateChanged -= LogActiveState;
    }

    private void LogActiveState(bool state)
    {
        print($"Current state - {state}");
    }
}
```

В SomeCanvas ивент вызывается, когда вызывают методы Activate/Deactivate.

В NotSomeCanvas подписываем в OnEnable метод LogActiveState на событие, соответственно в OnDisable отписываем.

Повнимательнее почитай о событиях, там, скорее всего, почти такой же пример и показывают.

`нет точного понимания, когда именно произойдет изменение свойства Interactable` А оно должно быть. Вызывая методы Activate/Deactivate хотя бы будет понятно откуда происходят изменения.